# Play! Framework Uglify js files

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, sbt, uglifyjs

I can't get *Play! Framework*'s uglify plugin to work.

I’ve added `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-uglify" % "1.0.3")` to **plugins.sbt**

Then, inside **build.sbt**, I modified:

`lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)`

to

`lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala, SbtWeb)`

and also added under that line:

`pipelineStages := Seq(uglify)`

After doing all this and re-running `sbt run` It doesn’t seem to be generating the **.min.js** files that it is supposed to. I manually checked on the target folder as well but no luck. Is there anything I might be doing wrong?

*(I’m using this plugin: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-uglify and Play! Framework v.2.5)*

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the Play 2.3.x [Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23#closure-compiler):

> UglifyJS 2 is presently provided via the RequireJS plugin (described next). The intent in future is to provide a standalone UglifyJS 2 plugin also for situations where RequireJS is not used.

So you should add the sbt-rjs plugin to your `plugins.sbt`.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.9")
```

Please mind the correct ordering of the plugins in `pipelineStages` in `build.sbt`as well.

```
pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, uglify)
```